# How to disallow unknown properties when updating mongodb collection with validation rules?

Tags: mongodb

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38101932
But since the anwser there is outdated and the linked "solution" isnt a direct answer I am posting it again.

I would like to disallow extra properties which are not declared in the schema. For example if the schema says :

```
"group1.a": {
  "$type": "int"
},
"group1.b": {
  "$type": "int"
}
```

I would like the following document to fail:

```
{
   "group1": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3
   }
}
```

How exactly can I make use of the jsonShema to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

There are two things that must be done:

1. Add `additionalProperties: false` to the `$jsonSchema`
2. Add `_id` field with `bsonType: objectId` as explicit property, otherwise every update fails (unless you do not explicitly set the _id when inserting new documents into the collection).

Answer (score -1):

From [the docs on schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) and [jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema):

Using the example below as an example, add the optional property: `additionalProperties: false`

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa", "address.city", "address.street" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            gender: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               minimum: 0,
               description: "must be a double and is required"
            },
            "address.city" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            "address.street" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Some additional reading available on the related dev ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30191

Comment: When updating the collection with a document containing random property names they are inserted successfully. How do I disallow fields that arent defined in the jsonSchema?

Comment: After your edit it would still fail. You need to add the _id field to the properties as well.

Comment: I imagine thats a common omission - but since its part of the schema (whether or not you specify it yourself in your model) I'd be inclined to specify it as a common gotcha rather than part of the rule.